# Why isn't this array working?

Tags: php, arrays, class

The array starts here:

```
public $link = array();
```

Keys and values are assigned through the following function:

```
public function build_links(){
        $this->link['career']     =     $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?p_id=13';
        $this->link['news']       =     $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?p_id=14';
    }
```

The value is used in following way:

```
<a href="<?php $this->link['news']?>">news</a>
```

The link should come up with "p_id=14" but its coming with "p_id=1" even though that value was never assigned and the PHP file is not returning any error.
I dont know this is happening. Little help here would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you should echo $this->link

Comment: `$this` is undefined outside of class methods. Where is located the code outputting link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed to [echo](http://www.php.net/echo) it, change to:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->link['news']; ?>">news</a>
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot to Sudhir and Nickparsa.
I tried with "echo" as well just a while ago but I dont know why it was not working!!! but is working now. Thank you so much guys.